# Why does my function work w/ pattern matching but not w/ if-then-else?

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec parity n = if (n = 0) then 
                    print_string "even" else if (n = 1)
                    print_string "odd" else 
                    parity (n-2);;
```

In comparison to...

```
let rec parity n = 
match n with
| 0 -> "even"
| 1 -> "odd"
| _ -> parity(n-2);;
```

I'm still new to this language. The error in the if-then-else is specifically on my print_string statements w/ a syntax error.

Comment: Sidenote: you can save a lot of iterations by checking `parity (n mod 2)`

Answer (score 3):

Your second `if` is missing its `then`.

(The expression after `if` doesn't need to be parenthesized in OCaml, incidentally.)

Comment: It's been a long day...Thanks!